# How to make literalinclude include precise C functions

Tags: python-sphinx

I would like to include part of a C header or a C file into my sphinx doc.
using literalinclude gets the whole file but I would like to get only some part but based on functions, struct names etc...
I don't want to use lines or start-with options as I would like to make it fail when the C idiom is not found.

I don't see any option or extension to do that.

Comment: "make it fail when the C idiom is not found" - what do you mean by that?

Comment: I meant that if I try to include :c:func:Foo and Foo does not exist in the file, sphinx-build fails as it cannot include the code for that symbol. An extension like sphinx-c-autodoc ( https://github.com/speedyleion/sphinx-c-autodoc) would do the job but it does not include the code.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `:pyobject:`, but for C? https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-literalinclude

Comment: Yep exactly ! When including C code with litteralinclude it gets the entire file